# How to change document.referrer when having server side redirect?

Tags: javascript, refer, referrer-policy

I have a service A that, when reaching it with url `www.y.com` (for example) returns a 302 redirect with Location header, with url `www.x.com`.
So, When Im using my chrome browser and go to `www.y.com`, I get a redirect `to www.x.com`, but when I use chrome dev tools and check document.referrer I see an empty referrer ('').
I tried to add Referer header (with `www.x.com` or Referrer-Policy header with origin but could not make document.referrer to return the desired `www.y.com`.

I have control on service A and domain [www.x.com](http://www.x.com), I also control the request to service A (can add headers)

Im expecting to see `www.x.com` when checking document.referrer

Comment: What do you actually need this for? Considering that the referrer is massively unreliable (it could be faked, or completely blocked, by a browser extension outside of your control), basing any _critical_ decisions on it, would be a bad idea to begin - at most, it has some "informational value" for stats.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I have some data on the referrer that I cannot currently get from any other source, so passing it somehow is pretty crucial for my use case.

Comment: If it is crucial, then using the referrer for it should be absolutely out of the question to begin with. Append the data in the query string with your redirect instead then. (Maybe "encode" it somehow, if you don't want to expose the content to the user; maybe redirect back to the URL without any query string directly after you stored the values into a session, if you want that for aesthetic reasons, or use the HTML5 history API for that last part.)

Comment: You asked this [yesterday too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77185231/document-referrer-is-empty-after-redirect)